# How to skip unittests when using mvn scm:bootstrap

Tags: maven, maven-scm

I'm trying to use the mvn scm plugin to check out the daily tag, and create an assembly from that version of the code. I configured the scm plugin and everythhing is working well, except that I can not seem to tell it to not run the unittests.

I tried:

- Passing the -Dmaven.test.skip=true command line parameter
- Creating a profile where the surefire plugin skips test, and list that profile in the scm configuration "profiles" section
- setting the "maven.test.skip=true" as an environment variable

In all cases, when the scm plugin starts running the goals I told it to run in the configuration (see below), it also runs the unittests.

Below is the example I used to skip tests by using a profile:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <goals>install,assembly:assembly</goals>
        <profiles>skiptest</profiles>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And this is the profile (I defined this in the pom.xml of the project):

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>skiptest</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

The command I use to do the checkout and bootstrap is:

```
mvn scm:bootstrap -DscmVersion=daily-20110427-421 -DscmVersionType=tag
```

I'm running mvn 2.2.1 on a Linux machine, and doing a checkout from a CVS repository. It's an existing project, I have continuous integration and tagging all up and running, I just want to check out a daily tag and create an assembly from that.

Any tips are much appreciated.

**Edit:** Got it to work with the answer below, but only after I upgraded to maven-scm-plugin version 1.1. Apparently, 1.0 did not propagate profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in the profile:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>skiptest</id>
        <properties>
            <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it didn't seem to work, but I added a help:active-profiles in the scm goals and I notice that the "skiptest" profile is not activated for some reason. Looking into that now.

Comment: Got it to work beautifully with your tip, and upgrading to scm plugin 1.1 (I was using 1.0) Thanks!